# Buddypress Member list not showing admin and mods

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, buddypress

I'm trying to get a list of members for a buddy press group but the result leaves out members that are admins or mods even though exclude_admins_mods=false has been specified as a parameter. This is what my code is

```
    global $bp;
    $id = 1;
    if (bp_group_has_members('group_id='.$id.'&exclude_admins_mods=false')) : 
        while ( bp_group_members() ) : bp_group_the_member(); 
             bp_group_member_link();
             echo '<br>';
        endwhile;

    else: ?>
      <div id="message" class="info">
        <p>no members.</p>
      </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Have I missed anything obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this `global $bp;`

Try passing an array:

```
$id = 1;
$args = array( 'group_id' => $id, 'exclude_admins_mods' => false);
if ( bp_group_has_members( $args ) ) :
```

Comment: This worked. I was under the impression that the arguments had to be provided as a string.